# Issue with Android List view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, radio-button, android-edittext

I have a list view in my app. In the list view I have 2 radio buttons and 5 checkboxes and one edit box..I have to enable the checkboxes when the user clicks one of the radio buttons and to disable them when the other one is clicked. Some times it works correctly. but sometimes it is not changes it state on button switch and also after scrolling the list. Another issue is editbox in the is list not getting focus. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First u have to set the tag by `setTag()` for each views in list.
After that for radio group u can do like this..

```
radioview = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id...);
radioview.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
switch (checkedId) {
case R.id.bt1:
   if (checkedId == -1) {
   checkedLayout.setEnabled(false);
      } else if (checkedId == R.id.rb2) {
    checkedLayout.setEnabled(true);
}
break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have set the tag for Radiogroup.Is it require to set tag for easch radio button?

Comment: Ok.I will check and let you know the result